# how to automatically null terminate char[] inside array

Tags: c++

I have this code and I want for each `char[]` inside `message` struct will be null terminated in order to avoid print all the memory values. if I create a single element it poses no problem. but when I have several elements in a `msg` array when I null terminate the char and when I add a new element it seems to overwrite and the null terminate will disapear!

```
    typedef unsigned char byte;

    enum msgType {
        tree = 2
    };

    struct header {
        msgType _type;
        unsigned _value;
        };

    struct message {
        uint16_t x;
        bool b;
        char c[5];
    };



    void allocateHeader(int value, byte* buffer, int size) {
        header* t = (header*)buffer;
        memset(buffer, 0, size);
        t->_type = tree;
        t->_value = value;
    }

    int main() {

            byte buffer[1000];
            std::string str = "hello";
            std::string str2 = "fooo";
            allocateHeader(8, buffer, 20);

            message msg1;
            msg1.x = 18;
            msg1.b = false;
            memset(msg1.c, 0, 5);
            memcpy(msg1.c, str.c_str(), 5);
            msg1.c[5] = '\0';

            message msg2;
            msg2.x = 1;
            msg2.b = true;
            memset(msg2.c, 0, 4);
            memcpy(msg2.c, str2.c_str(), 4);
            msg2.c[4] = '\0';

            message msg[2];
            msg[0] = msg1;
            msg[0].c[5] = '\0';
            msg[1] = msg2;
            msg[1].c[4] = '\0';


            memcpy(&buffer[sizeof(header)], &msg, sizeof(msg));



            message msgrecp[2];
            message* msgp = (message*)&buffer[8];
            for(auto i=0; i < 2; i++){
                msgrecp[i] = *msgp;
                std::string str(msgrecp[i].c);
                std::cout << msgrecp[i].b << " " << str << " " << msgrecp[i].x << std::endl;
                //print 
                //0 hello[|[#{[ 18
                //1 fooo 1
                msgp = (message*)&buffer[8 + sizeof(message)];
            }
    


            return 0;

        }
```

Comment: `"hello"` doesn't fit in `char[5]`

Answer (score 0):

`message::c` is `char[5]`

so `c[5]='\0'` access outside of bound

---

[`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) does contain the null terminate char, you can simply copy `length()+1` given long enough buffer (not true in the code).

---

btw `memset(msg.c, 0, 4)` followed by `memcpy(msg.c, str.c_str(), 4)` doesn't make much sense, why you fill it if you're going to overwrite it immediately?